# Strange behaviour of UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, viewdidload

I have to set an **initial** scroll position of my *UITableView* to a row other than the first one (for example, the first row of the second section).

In my view controller's *viewDidLoad* I write:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // self.view is a container view, not UITableView
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]
       atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
}
```

When the screen loads, the scroll position is **not** set immediately. Otherwise, when the *animated* parameter is set to YES, the position is set immediately without any animation. **What's going on?**

**What's the correct way to set initial row position for UITableView?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best place should be ViewDidAppear. Moreover, you should invoke scroll method in cellWillDisplay to make sure. Remember to check indexPath before invoking scroll method

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but have you tried to put this code into viewDidAppear{}?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` since the table most likely haven't been populated by then (at least it wasn't in my case)

Try putting it in an NSTimer instead once your table loads and calling it then.

As an aside, I quickly put this code (with animation) into a nav bar button item and it worked very well after the table was finished loading.

Comment: The scrolling works even in viewDidLoad, but it scrolls not immediately. NSTimer is some kind of hack to my mind. Is there any callback for table did load event?

Comment: Correct, it won't scroll until the data exists to scroll to.  On projects where you have a large amount of tableview data or images, it can take 2 seconds or more and by then `viewDidLoad` was already called.  Unfortunately there is nothing in the `UITableViewDelegate` method for when a table is done loading.  You might find more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483581/get-notified-when-uitableview-has-finished-asking-for-data