# Can not select row in UITableView on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I am working on an iPad app with a split view controller.  I have a stock standard UITableView as the master view.

When the view opens, I would like it to select the first row in the list.

In ViewDidLoad I have:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

When I run the app in the simulator it seems to select the first row (flashes) but then it is no longer selected.  It is like something is clearing the selection after the ViewDidLoad method.  I can touch and select rows just fine.  Is there a property on the row or the prototype cell I need to set for this to work correctly?

Thanks in advance,
Richard

Comment: Are you sure you are running this code "late" enough?

Comment: In your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndex:` method, are you deselecting the row manually using `[tableView deselectRowAtIndex:]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing that in the `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`.

**Edit:**

Just one thing Richard, this works because when you actually enter in the `viewDidAppear` your `UITableView` has been fully reloaded. In case it hasn't, it wouldn't work. You can actually do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483581/get-notified-when-uitableview-has-finished-asking-for-data), which I recommend (check the comment from Eric Morand).

Comment: Thank you so much!  Putting it in viewDidAppear did the trick.