# layoutSubviews in UIViewTableCell does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, position, label

I have a class PostListTableCell, inheriting UITableViewCell, which is used as my custom cell in a UITableView.

I need to resize some labels in the cell, so I called following method in

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [_titleLabel sizeToFit];
}
```

But the problem is, when the UITableView loaded, the _titleLabel does not resize:

[image]

But after I click this cell and select it, the title did resize:

[image]

Following is the code to load data:

```
- (PostListTableCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *PostListTableCellIdentifier = @"PostListTableCell";
    PostListTableCell *cell = (PostListTableCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PostListTableCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PostListTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:PostListTableCellIdentifier];
    }

   Post *post = (Post*)_posts[indexPath.row];
    [cell loadPost:post];

    return cell;
}
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in -layoutSubviews to see when exactly it gets called?

Comment: are you using auto layout?

Comment: Are you sure your layoutSubviews is getting called at right time?

Comment: @MirkoCatalano, that is exactly the point!!!!! Thanks!!!! BTW, could you explain a bit more? Why does autolayout can cause such problem?

Comment: @JefferyThomas, I tried, and did not find problems. In fact, problem is solved by Mirko's suggestion now.

Comment: @eagle.dan.1349, my layoutSubviews is inside the PostListTableCell class, which I believe is in the right place....In fact, problem is solved by Mirko's suggestion.

Comment: the problem was that autolayout resize your label after your set again because it follow the constraints and not the frame set

Comment: I make an answer the other people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the **autolayout** that resize again the label for you with the constraints that you had set when you make the label in Interface Build, unfortunately in under **autolayout** the the hierarchy is *Constraints* > *Frame*

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you use Autolayout in (**viewDidLoad**) method which is related to **UIViewController** and its subclasses and (**awakeFromNib**) which is related to **UIView** and **UITableViewCell** etc all Views Frames' **have not been rendered yet** while those methods called.

So if you want to resize any of outlets you should call it in (**ViewDidAppear**) for **UIViewController**. In **UIViews** and **cells** you should use:

```
- (void)layoutSubViews
{
     [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

And **don't forget** to set **interval** to your Method of resizing as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10772828/5135943).

Comment: i have  a concern about setting an interval , what is the ideal milliseconds taken for rendering , and what if i have too many subviews , is this the best soultion out there in terms of performance and responsiveness  ?

Answer (score -1):

set frame for your label

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(20, 30, 200, 50);
   _titleLabel.frame = frame;
}
```