# Cell layout messing up when Auto-layout is ON

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, autolayout

I am trying to create a `UITableview`, with grouped static cells, that contain `UITextField`s. Everything looks fine, until I put in the `UITextField`s. Anyone have any ideas as to what may be happening? Auto-layout is on. When Auto-layout is off it is fixed but then rest of project is messing up.

Here is a picture to show what is happening:[image]

Comment: try to turn AutoLayout off

Comment: It fixes it, but it messes up the rest of my project. Sorry, should of included that in the original post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842987/uitableviewcell-subclass-layout-messed-up-in-autolayout-disabled-storyboard

Comment: This answer confuses me if I'm completely honest. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: I would double check the constraints, one of them may be wrong, or creating conflicts.

Comment: Can you show the constrains here?

Comment: There aren't any constraints. Everything looks fine, until I put the UITextField's in the cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sussed it. Row height was set to "default". I changed this to custom (in this case, 44) and it fixed the issue.